# What could be causing "The leading minor of order 'n' is not positive definite"?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I have an algorithm that requires a matrix decomposition.

```
(lam, w) = eigh(Sb, Sw, eigvals_only=False)
```

Usually, this works.  However, for some datasets I have, it gives the error:

> numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: the leading minor of order 8 of 'b'
>   is not positive definite. The factorization of 'b' could not be
>   completed and no eigenvalues or eigenvectors were computed.

`Sb` and `Sw` are essentially kernel matrices based on the dataset.  The dataset that causes this has some rows and columns that are identical, but when I add some random Gaussian noise to it before running the algorithm all the rows and columns become independent.  Yet I'm still getting the problem.

I checked `Sb` and `Sw`, both have unique rows and columns and are symmetrical.  What other things should I check and what could be causing this issue?

Comment: I could imagine that if the added Gaussian noise is small i.r.t. the original data's amplitude and you thus have some *almost* dependent rows and columns, the problem will be numerically so ill-posed that you end up with the symptoms of *actually* dependent rows and columns due to rounding effects.

Comment: Even with large Gaussian noise, i.e. 1e-1, this still occurs.  Also when I do Sb = (Sb + Sb.T)/2, and the same for Sw.

Comment: It is almost certainly the case that your input matrices are not positive definite. Do they have a Cholesky decomposition?